# How to get the history of commit messages for a given author in a git branch?

Tags: git, git-log

I would like to get the history of commit messages for a given author in a git branch. Is there any easy way to achieve it other than to parse the log through programming?

***UPDATED:***

The following was expacted for me that does the same thing:

```
git log --author='some author' --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit
git log --author='some author' --oneline
```

`git log --help` mentioned the follows:

```
   Commit Formatting
       --pretty[=<format>], --format=<format>
           Pretty-print the contents of the commit logs in a given format, where <format> can be one of oneline, short, medium, full, fuller, email, raw and
           format:<string>. See the "PRETTY FORMATS" section for some additional details for each format. When omitted, the format defaults to medium.

           Note: you can specify the default pretty format in the repository configuration (see git-config(1)).

       --abbrev-commit
           Instead of showing the full 40-byte hexadecimal commit object name, show only a partial prefix. Non default number of digits can be specified
           with "--abbrev=<n>" (which also modifies diff output, if it is displayed).

           This should make "--pretty=oneline" a whole lot more readable for people using 80-column terminals.

       --no-abbrev-commit
           Show the full 40-byte hexadecimal commit object name. This negates --abbrev-commit and those options which imply it such as "--oneline". It also
           overrides the log.abbrevCommit variable.

       --oneline
           This is a shorthand for "--pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit" used together.
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean? All of the commit messages on commits by a specific author?

Comment: @jonrsharpe changed to messages. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give Author name as registered in GIT repo. Or the Author email address will also work.

e.g.

```
git log --author='Bharat Biswal'
git log --author='bharat.biswal@gmail.com'
```

[image]

Comment: You can optionally use their email address.

Comment: Thanks Justin. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

`git log --author=<author>`

If say you are looking for adam Brown commits

`git log --author="adam"`

`git log --author=adam`

`git log --author=Brown`

would also work. The quotes are optional if you don't need any spaces.

Add --all if you intend to search all branches and not just the current commit's ancestors in your repo.

So to list commits by adam or damian, you can do a regex like this:

`git log --author="\(damian\)\|\(adam\)"`

or

`git log --committer="\(damian\)\|\(amit\)"`

Answer (score 1):

`git log --author=<author name pattern>`
check the man page of [git log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---authorltpatterngt) for details.